# How to show posts in a WordPress theme using HTML 5?

Tags: html, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am pretty new in HTML 5 and I am developing a WordPress theme using HTML 5 and I have the following doubt:

I have to put this WordPress code that show all the posts in my page theme

```
<div id="content">
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>

        <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

            <div class="post">
                <h2 id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                <small><?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?> <!-- by <?php the_author() ?> --></small>

                <div class="entry">
                    <?php the_content('Read the rest of this entry »'); ?>
                </div>

                <p class="postmetadata">Posted in <?php the_category(', ') ?> <strong>|</strong> <?php edit_post_link('Edit','','<strong>|</strong>'); ?>  <?php comments_popup_link('No Comments »', '1 Comment »', '% Comments »'); ?></p>

                <!--
                <?php trackback_rdf(); ?>
                -->
            </div>

        <?php endwhile; ?>

        <div class="navigation">
            <div class="alignleft"><?php posts_nav_link('','','« Previous Entries') ?></div>
            <div class="alignright"><?php posts_nav_link('','Next Entries »','') ?></div>
        </div>

    <?php else : ?>

        <h2 class="center">Not Found</h2>
        <p class="center"><?php _e("Sorry, but you are looking for something that isn't here."); ?></p>
        <?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . "/searchform.php"); ?>

    <?php endif; ?>

</div>
```

Now in the previous code this php code is wrapped inside a classic XHTML **...** block. Now I want to optimize the previous code using **HTML 5**.

So is it a good choice replace the external **...**  with a **...** ?

Or are there a better solution?

After do this operation is it a good choice wrap every post using the HTML 5 **...** tag?

I mean that I replace this code:

```
<div class="post">
    ..................
    ..................
    ..................
</div>
```

with something like:

```
<article>
   ..................
   ..................
   ..................
</article>
```

Is it a good idea?

Tnx

Andrea

Comment: @AlienArrays no I can use HTML 4 without problem (exist also some old orrible template that use table for impagination...)

Comment: `<article></article>` in my opinion is the perfect substitution for `<div></div>` in this case.

Answer (score 1):

A great reference to check is the [underscores (_s) theme](https://github.com/automattic/_s). It's an HTML5 blank theme maintained by Automattic (the company who owns WP). Here's the template they use:

```
<article id="post-{ID#}” class="post-{ID#} post">  
  <header class="entry-header">
    <h1 class="entry-title”>…</h1>
    <div class="entry-meta”>…</div>
  </header>
  <div class="entry-content”>…</div>
  <footer class="entry-meta">…</footer>
</article>
```

Answer (score 0):

WordPress doesn't care which html its templates output, WordPress just echo's the content that's all. Your theme however could depend on the `.post` class but I guess you're making your own theme

Comment: Forgive me, but can you not just add the class to the article? If the developer has listed div.post in the css then they really need a talking too ;-)

Comment: Sure you can add it but that still doesn't mean it will work. Take this selector for example: ´.post-container div´ not as uncommon as your example, of course it would be weird because there's a class available, but... https://i.chzbgr.com/maxW500/1665425664/h97A49856/